# AngularJS SignalR integration code

Tags: angularjs, signalr

Trying to send update from mobile app , through server , to website( AngularJS) over signalR. It gets connected to hub, joins the group but don't get output on console( json) after sending update from mobile app. Did research, tried different syntax , no result.

```
    var hub = new Hub('chatHub', {
    //client side methods
    listeners:{
        'notifyJobStatusUpdate': function (json) {
             console.log(json);
             //var job = {parseJsonHere};
            //{do some business logic, refresh page for start}
            $rootScope.$apply();
        }
    },

    //handle connection error
    errorHandler: function(error){
        console.error(error);
    },
    withCredentials: false,

    rootPath: 'http://xxxxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/signalr',

    //server side methods
    methods: ['joinGroup'],

stateChanged: function(state){
    switch (state.newState) {
        case $.signalR.connectionState.connecting:
            console.log("signalR.connectionState.connecting");
            break;
        case $.signalR.connectionState.connected:
            console.log("signalR.connectionState.connected");
            hub.joinGroup("BusinessDashboard");
            console.log("joinGroup: BusinessDashboard");
            break;
        case $.signalR.connectionState.reconnecting:
            console.log("signalR.connectionState.reconnecting");
            break;
        case $.signalR.connectionState.disconnected:
            console.log("signalR.connectionState.disconnected");
            break;
    }
}
});
}]);
```

Comment: Maybe a typo: log.console should be console.log

Comment: Good catch but actually i have it correctly in the code, just made mistake in the posting. Corrected.

Comment: SignalR on Azure....arrgh....it works ok over the website, right?

Comment: Have you verified that the messages from the mobile app are getting to the Hub successfully? And can you call methods from your AngularJS app on the server?